# The cost of Azure Virtual Machines

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm looking at the cost for VMs on azure and it looks like I can get standard dedicated server from a local provider that would effectively be 8 times cheaper for the same spec.

Is that possible or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? This isn't the place to compare pricing with hosting providers. Plus, you've shared zero details about your "same spec." Regardless: Completely off-topic for StackOverflow, as it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Azure IaaS will not always be the cheapest one. Question is if your local provider can provide also APIs for automation of deployment, networking services, scalability sets etc. ... things to consider besides the cost of the metal.

You are not always buying vendor IaaS based on price but also considering other facts and services.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the basic cost for the dedicated server, you will also incur costs for the racking&stacking and the space in the datacenter, heating & cooling and added maintenance.